# Is it possible to consume a typescript interface that does not fully match the data

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have an interface with fixed number of properties

```
export interface Page {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  heading: string | string[];
}
```

The data represented by that object comes from cms, however there are some dynamic properties that cms can return, these properties completely driven by cms so defining them as nullable (`prop?: ...`) within Page interface does not make any sense because there are too many props like that:

```
export interface Page {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  heading: string | string[];
  dynamicProp1?: string;
  dynamicProp2?: string;
}
```

So if I use that `Page` type the code-editor when accessing one of these one of that props. e.g:

```
const firstPage: Page = service.getPage('byId');
const dynamicPropX  = firstPage.dunamicPropX; //does not exist on interface but some exist in returned object.
```

I wonder if there any solution for that or should I just stick to `any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the use case for [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

> Sometimes you don’t know all the names of a type’s properties ahead of time, but you do know the shape of the values.

```
export interface Page {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  heading: string | string[];
  [dynamicKeys: string]: string | string[] // Must be compatible with the fixed keys
}

declare const firstPage: Page;
const dynamicPropX  = firstPage.dunamicPropX; // Okay, but any key is now okay as well
//    ^? string | string[]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBUwHM8BvAKDjhgRgBtgAuOAZximSIG5K4ATYC2wcwNCEmZsOSbrwAWwTH06T2nOAB9WamQG0Aujyq6+ATySYAtgmwBpYKZarpRfc-VapnA3AD0vuABZAFc2OAAjPGwISzBMGnCGOAB3WjlqBTh0BBBgPjgAawcWcgBfcnIBbDpMKCjxMOyoNkISZlbgHmikMLMLa2x8KAgwAA0qAF4shGaYDoA6PmD+myGR0a4-AIB5AsxTABoI4PhMJFNCh0QWOCQIZLgIPYvMG+TgOjpyfyoqAD0APzkIA)

Comment: oh that is really interesting, basically you can assign any conditional type to that, right?

Comment: oh, actually I have to make it compatible with the fixed keys, now I see what you mean. But that composite type is not limited to the fixed keys types, isn't it?

Comment: "_that composite type is not limited to the fixed keys types_": I am not sure I exactly understand what you mean, but the index signature type must allow the types for each fixed keys (basically a union of all types, but can be more as well). On the other hand, the type for a fixed key can be more restrictive, and if you access that fixed key, you would get only that type, not the entire union. https://tsplay.dev/mL2Xbw